# Rewrite QDataStream operator >> () equivalent into to C++ without Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following Qt C++ code

```
// QByteArray data;
QDataStream ds(data.right(data.size()-start));
ds.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

qint8 sz;
ds >> sz;
```

and want to transfer it into normal C++ code without Qt. My first attempt is:

```
// std::vector<char> data;
std::string ds( data.cbegin() , data.cbegin() + start );
```

What operation do I need to perform to mimic the operator>>(qint8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the dependencies between `QByteArray` and `QDataStream` and other parts of Qt aren't much. You can easily add the `qbytearray[.cpp|.h|_p.h]` and `qdatastream[.cpp|.h|_p.h]`, along with a global header or two, and you should be able to compile them without rest of Qt. That's what `qmake` does, for example. Note that `qmake` gets built without Qt, only from a makefile and some Qt sources.

Having said that, the standard C++ library doesn't come with functionality of a `QDataStream`.

A `std::string` is not like a `QByteArray` nor like a `QDataStream`. `std::vector<uint8_t>` is what you need to store the raw data in replacement of `QByteArray`.

You'll need to implement a `QDataStream` replacement yourself.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

class QDataStream {
public:
    typedef std::vector<uint8_t> Storage;
    enum ByteOrder { BigEndian, LittleEndian };
    enum Status { Ok, ReadPastEnd };
private:
    std::shared_ptr<const Storage> m_ptr;
    const Storage * m_data;
    size_t m_idx;
    Status m_status;
    ByteOrder m_byteOrder, m_systemOrder;
    static ByteOrder systemByteOrder() {
        const uint32_t t = 1;
        return (reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&t)) ? LittleEndian : BigEndian;
    }
    bool has(size_t count) const { return m_idx + count <= m_data->size(); }
    template <typename T> QDataStream & read(T & i) {
        if (has(sizeof(T)) && Ok == m_status) {
            T result = *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&(*m_data)[m_idx]);
            m_idx += sizeof(T);
            if (m_byteOrder != m_systemOrder) {
                T tmp = 0;
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
                    tmp = (tmp << 8) | (result & 0xFF);
                    result = result >> 8;
                }
                i = tmp;
            } else
                i = result;
        } else {
            m_status = ReadPastEnd;
        }
        return *this;
    }
public:
    QDataStream(const std::vector<uint8_t> * data) :
        m_data(data), m_idx(0), m_status(Ok),
        m_byteOrder(BigEndian), m_systemOrder(systemByteOrder()) {}
    QDataStream(std::shared_ptr<Storage> data) :
        m_ptr(data), m_data(m_ptr.get()), m_idx(0), m_status(Ok),
        m_byteOrder(BigEndian), m_systemOrder(systemByteOrder()) {}
    QDataStream(std::unique_ptr<Storage> && data) :
        m_ptr(data.release()), m_data(m_ptr.get()), m_idx(0), m_status(Ok),
        m_byteOrder(BigEndian), m_systemOrder(systemByteOrder()) {}
    QDataStream(Storage && data) :
        m_ptr(new Storage(std::move(data))), m_data(m_ptr.get()),
        m_idx(0), m_status(Ok), m_byteOrder(BigEndian), m_systemOrder(systemByteOrder()) {}
    bool atEnd() const { return m_idx == m_data->size(); }
    QDataStream & operator>>(int8_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    QDataStream & operator>>(int16_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    QDataStream & operator>>(int32_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    QDataStream & operator>>(uint8_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    QDataStream & operator>>(uint16_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    QDataStream & operator>>(uint32_t & i) {
        return read(i);
    }
    void setByteOrder(ByteOrder b) { m_byteOrder = b; }
    ByteOrder byteOrder() const { return m_byteOrder; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    uint32_t val;
    QDataStream s_be(&v);
    s_be >> val;
    assert(val == 0x01020304); // big endian
    QDataStream s_le(&v);
    s_le.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    s_le >> val;
    assert(val == 0x04030201); // little endian
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close enough to what I was looking for :-)