# istream for char buffer

Tags: c++, stl, istream

In Qt library there QByteArray and QDataStream classes, which allow me to read and write variables to memmory buffer with very easy to use syntax:

```
QByteArray data = getData();
QDataStream stream( data );
double d = 0;
int i = 0;
stream >> d >> i;
```

How to implement simmilar behavior with only stl stream classes?
For example I have a const char* data and size of it, so I want to construct std::istream and read varibles from that data:

```
const char* data = getData();
size_t size = getSize();

membuffer buf( data, data + size );
std::istream str( buf );
double d = 0;
str >> d;
```

Note that data should not be copied!

Comment: `std::xstream` classes have the functionality of `QTextStream`, *not* `QDataStream`. There's nothing in C++ standard library that resembles `QDataStream`. Generally speaking, `std::istream` will be useless for your purpose. Reimplementing `QDataStream` is [not hard at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31687943/1329652).

Comment: Once the invalid assumptions are corrected, this is possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31686553/1329652).

Comment: @KubaOber: given that the request was to do something like that using standard streams, question you pointed to (and even more so the answer) are clearly _not_ the answer...

Comment: @DietmarKühl Standard streams are a drop-in replacement for most of `QTextStream`. There's no point to them if all you want is binary serialization, and `QDataStream` does binary serialization. The question is based on an invalid assumption. Just because `QDataStream` and `std::istream` contain "stream" in their name, doesn't make one the replacement of the other.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a fixed sized data buffer and its size it is trivial to implement by creating a suitable stream buffer:

```
struct membuf: std::streambuf {
     membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
         this->setg(begin, begin, end);
     }
};
```

This simple stream buffer just sets up the stream buffers "get-area" to be the range `[begin, end)` (`begin` is used twice as it is possible to set up a "put-back area" which in this case is empty). When there are no more characters to read the stream will try to call `underflow()` whose default implementation indicates failure. If you want to read more characters you'd overwrite `underflow()` to provide more characters in a newly set up buffer.

With that you can create a stream using this memory backed stream buffer:

```
membuf       sbuf(begin, end);
std::istream in(&sbuf);
double d = 0;
if (in >> d) { // always check conversions from string to a value...
    // ...
}
```

For a bit of extra convenience, the creation of the stream buffer and the stream can also be bundled into a class. There is a small trick in that the stream buffer should be created reasonably earlier but it is doable:

```
class imemstream: private virtual membuf, public std::istream {
public:
    imemstream(char* begin, char* end)
        : membuf(begin, end)
        , std::ios(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
        , std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }
};
```

Just a warning, though: creating a stream is more expensive than copying quite a bit of data. That is, if you want to use that stream in a loop you probably want to provide functionality to reset the buffer (probably combined with clearing state flags).

Comment: `QDataStream` has nothing to do with text conversions, though... It's a binary stream used for binary serialization, not text serialization.

Comment: @KubaOber: the request is to read from an `std::istream` using `str >> d`. That is clearly reading text formatted data.

Comment: Kuba Ober is rigth I don't need to read and opearte on strings, I need binary deserialization.

Comment: @Jeka: `std::istream`'s `operator>>()` are for converting text into values. You need a different tool in that case. The standard C++ library doesn't have any tools for converting from binary data to values.